# System tray message alert when result > 0

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, system-tray

There is a function that user can send message each other and it's data saved to table. And I wrote that simple code below that check's new message from database:

```
lDataParameter.Add("msg", _msgEnd);

ultragrid1.DataSource = _msgEnd.Tables[0];

if (ultragrid1.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    ultragrid1.Rows[0].Selected = true;

    MessageBox.Show("You have" + ultragrid1.Rows.Count.ToString() + " 1 new message"); 
}
```

It works! Now I want to display that message box on system tray however app closed...

How to get my app on system tray?

Comment: Look up [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.notifyicon.aspx).

Comment: Use this guide: https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-tray-applications-in-.net-a-practical-guide/

Comment: There's no such thing as the system tray. You are looking for the notification area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys. I did it.

```
 public Form1()
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.contextMenu1 = new System.Windows.Forms.ContextMenu();
            this.menuItem1 = new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem();

            // Initialize contextMenu1 
            this.contextMenu1.MenuItems.AddRange(
                        new System.Windows.Forms.MenuItem[] { this.menuItem1 });

            // Initialize menuItem1 
            this.menuItem1.Index = 0;
            this.menuItem1.Text = "E&xit";
            this.menuItem1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.menuItem1_Click);

            // Set up how the form should be displayed. 
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(292, 266);
            this.Text = "Notify Icon Example";

            // Create the NotifyIcon. 
            this.notifyIcon1 = new System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon(this.components);

            // The Icon property sets the icon that will appear 
            // in the systray for this application.
            notifyIcon1.Icon = new Icon("Icon.ico");

            // The ContextMenu property sets the menu that will 
            // appear when the systray icon is right clicked.
            notifyIcon1.ContextMenu = this.contextMenu1;

            // The Text property sets the text that will be displayed, 
            // in a tooltip, when the mouse hovers over the systray icon.
            notifyIcon1.Text = "Form1 (NotifyIcon example)";
            notifyIcon1.Visible = true;

            // Handle the DoubleClick event to activate the form.
            notifyIcon1.DoubleClick += new System.EventHandler(this.notifyIcon1_DoubleClick);

        }
```

Now I want to create more menu this.

menuItem1.Index = 1;
                this.menuItem1.Text = "I&nfo";

How to create with it?